# What is the step-by-step process of transferring money from India to the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, money-transfer, international-transfer

I am a UK national and looking to buy my first property here. My father lives in India wants to help me with the initial deposit. From what I have been reading in some forums, I am not clear with the process of transferring money from India to UK.

I want to get INR 50 Lakhs transferred to Pound Sterling.

Could anyone help me giving a step by step process of getting the funds transferred and what is the bank fees/ transfer rates going to be? Or is there a currency transfer agency who does this kind of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Banks allow to make an international transfer. As the amounts is very small, there is no paperwork required. Have your dad walk into any Bank and request for a transfer. He should be knowing your Bank's SWIFT BIC, Name and Address and account number.

Edit:
Under the liberalised remittance scheme, any individual can transfer upto 1 million USD or eq. A CA certificate is required. Please get in touch with your bank in India for exact steps

Comment: Hi Dheer, the amount is 50 Lakh's. I have updated the question.